# Explicit $\mathbb{C}$-algebra isomorphism $\mathbb{C}[\mathbb{Z}/2] \simeq \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Explicit $\mathbb{C}$-algebra isomorphism $\mathbb{C}[\mathbb{Z}/2] \simeq \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$

I know $\mathbb{C}[\mathbb{Z}/2]=\mathbb{C}(1+\sigma)\oplus \mathbb{C}(1-\sigma)$ where $-1=\sigma \in \mathbb{Z}/2 =\{{±1}\}$

How do I construct an isomorphism?

Comment: You already have an isomorphism, the moment you think about what $\mathbb{C}(1+\sigma)\oplus \mathbb{C}(1-\sigma)$ means.

Comment: $\{a+a\sigma\}\oplus \{b-b\sigma\}$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$

I am confused about what the direct sum means in this case and what sigma is...

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I don't have much time right now, but I'll write down the details in an answer in a few hours, unless someone else does first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, what does $\Bbb C[\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z]$ mean? This is a construction known as a *group ring*, and it works the following way: Given a ring $R$ and a group $G$ (written multiplicatively), the group ring $R[G]$ consists of elements ("monomials") of the form $r\cdot g$, with $r\in R,g\in G$, or finite sums of such monomials. If you have two monomials $r\cdot g$ and $s\cdot h$, the product $(r\cdot g)(s\cdot h)=(rs)\cdot (gh)$. If you have two elements that are not monomials, their product is evaluated by expanding brackets the usual way.

If you think about polynomials when reading this, that's not entirely wrong; the two concepts are related, although ultimately different. The polynomial ring with coefficients in a ring $R$ would in this case be $R[(\Bbb N,+)]$, where $r\cdot n$ for $r\in R, n\in \Bbb N$ corresponds to $rx^n$ in the polynomial ring. So a polynomial ring is not a group ring because the $x^n$'s do not come from a group, but rather a monoid.

Also of note is the fact that we have, for instance, $r\cdot g+s\cdot g=(r+s)\cdot g$, but be careful not to write $r\cdot g+r\cdot h=r\cdot(g+h)$, because there is no addition in $G$. Also, if $e\in G$ is the identity, some might feel it convenient to shorten $r\cdot e$ into just $r$, and similarly $1\cdot g$ to $g$. This is sloppy, and bound to lead to mistakes unless you're already used to working with group rings.

In this case, we have the ring $\Bbb C$ and the group $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z =\{\sigma,\tau\}$ where $\tau=\sigma^2$. This means that every element of $\Bbb C[\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z]$ is of the form $z\cdot\sigma+w\cdot \tau$, for some complex $z,w$. Now that we know what we're dealing with, what can we do?

We note that if we set $\alpha= 1\cdot\tau+1\cdot\sigma$ and $\beta = 1\cdot\tau-1\cdot\sigma$, then $\alpha\beta=0$. Also, every element in $\Bbb C[\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z]$ can be written uniquely as a linear combination of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with coefficients of the form $z\cdot\tau$. For instance, $3\cdot\tau+(1-i)\cdot\sigma=((2-\frac i2)\cdot\tau)\alpha +((1+\frac i2)\cdot\tau)\beta$. This decomposition into an $\alpha$ component and a $\beta$ component is what they mean by $\mathbb{C}(1+\sigma)\oplus \mathbb{C}(1-\sigma)$, or as I would write it according to what I said above, $\mathbb{C}(1\cdot\tau+1\cdot\sigma)\oplus \mathbb{C}(1\cdot\tau-1\cdot\sigma)$.

I now claim that using the coefficients of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ gives us an isomorphism between $\Bbb C[\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z]$ and $\Bbb C\times \Bbb C$. For instance, the image of $3\cdot \tau+(1-i)\cdot\sigma$ is $(2-\frac i2, 1+\frac i2)$. You need to check that this is a homomorphism, and that it is a bijection. Technically, you also need to show that it is even a well-defined map, in other words that the decomposition of an element into a linear combination of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is unique.

Comment: I'm having some trouble showing it is an isomorphism. How do I show isomorphisms for C-algebras?

Comment: @Bob The same way you show isomorphism for anything else: you show that the homomorphism you have is invertible.

Comment: @Bob No, the map is given by $\alpha\mapsto (1,0)$ and $\beta\mapsto (0,1)$.